# Does every ordinal appearing in a model of ZF appear in a model of ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

To be more precise, suppose that $M$ is a model of ZF, for simplicity (or tactility) a set in some larger model $V$ of ZFC+Con(ZF), and suppose that $M\vDash``\alpha$ is an ordinal$"$. Must there be a model $N$ of ZFC (appearing in $V$) such that $\alpha\in N$ and an isomorphism of the partial structures given by the transitive closures of $\alpha$ in $M$ and $N$?

If yes, then can we also assume that $M$ and $N$ agree on cardinality for ordinals ${\leq}\alpha$?

Comment: Note that we can always get choice by *shrinking*: if $M\models\mathsf{ZF}$ then $L^M\models\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $M$ and $L^M$ "agree on the ordinals" (although of course they may disagree about cardinalities). In the other direction, many **but not all** models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ have tame class forcing extensions with the same ordinals to models of choice. Gitik's model, in which all uncountable ordinals are singular, is an example where this can't be done.

Comment: I mean, we covered the Feferman–Levy model in class...

Comment: @AsafKaragila does FefLev necessarily not admit a model of ZFC agreeing on cardinalities of ordinals? We'd disagree on cofinality, but nothing immediately strikes me as contradictory.

Comment: No, because if $M$ is the FL model, and $N$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$ with the same ordinals, then either $\omega_1^M$ is countable, or $\omega_1^M=\omega_\omega^N$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Noah mentioned in the comments, the answer to the first question is "yes".

The answer to the second question is consistently "no", assuming a little consistency: if there is a transitive model of ZF in $V$, then there will be transitive models $M$ of ZF in $V$ and ordinals $\alpha$ of $M$ for which the extra requirement fails. For let $P$ be a countable transitive model of ZF of minimal height. Let $Q=L^P$, so $Q$ models ZFC and has the same ordinals as does $P$ (and $Q$ is also countable). Let $\lambda=\aleph_\omega^Q$. So $Q\models$ "$\lambda$ is singular". Let $G$ be $(Q,\mathrm{Coll}(\omega,{<\lambda}))$-generic. Let $\mathbb{R}^*$ be the resulting symmetric set of reals, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^*=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}\mathbb{R}\cap Q[G\upharpoonright\alpha]$. Let $M=(L(\mathbb{R}^*))^{Q[G]}$. Then $M\models$ ZF and $\mathbb{R}^*=\mathbb{R}\cap M$ and $M\models$ "$\lambda=\omega_1$", so $M\models$ "$\omega_1$ is singular", since $Q=L^M\subseteq M$.

Now suppose there is a model $N$ of ZFC such that the ordinals of $N$ which are ${\leq\lambda}$ are (externally) isomorphic to those of $M$ which are ${\leq\lambda}$, and $M,N$ have the same cardinals $\leq\lambda$. Thus, $\lambda=\omega_1^N$. But $L_\lambda^N=L_\lambda^M$, and the sequence $\left<\aleph_n^{L^M}\right>_{n<\omega}=\left<\aleph_n^{L_\lambda^M}\right>_{n<\omega}$ is definable over $L_\lambda^M$, so it is in $N$, so $N\models$ "$\lambda$ is singular", a contradiction.

(Without the assumption that $\lambda+1$ is wellfounded, it doesn't seem clear that we must get $L_\lambda^N=L_\lambda^M$, so the last paragraph seems to become problematic.)